# OpenGL with SDL and GLEW, error:48

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, sdl-2, glew

I started to make a little OpenGL program following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4az5VDpxVw&index=14&list=PLSPw4ASQYyymu3PfG9gxywSPghnSMiOAW

It all worked fine until i came to tutorial 11. Since then, it does builds just fine, but when i want to run the compiled program, it just outputs

```
    error: 48
```

in the console and closes instantly.

So i did a little research but i did not find anyone else having this problem, all i found was this:

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232611(v=vs.60).aspx

And i am not even sure, if that has something to do with my problem.

Strangely, this has never happened before, this problem first occured, when i came to tutorial 11 in the playlist, added picoPNG and wrote the code to load the png file up for me. While adding picoPNG i also got some errors saying "size_t has not been declared", but i fixed that by adding the line

```
    #include <stddef.h>
```

at the top of picoPNG.cpp.

I am using Eclipse CDT 8.8.0 with MinGW w32 20150801, glew 1.13.0 (i compiled the source code with MinGW) and SDL2 2.0.4 on Windows 10.

The commands i used to compile GLEW with MinGW were these:

```
    gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude  -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.o -c src/glew.c
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a    -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
    ar cr lib/libglew32.a src/glew.o

    gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_MX -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude  -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.mx.o -c src/glew.c
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32mx.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32mx.dll.a -o lib/glew32mx.dll src/glew.mx.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
    ar cr lib/libglew32mx.a src/glew.mx.o
```

(i did this with a batch file located in the glew-1.13.0 folder)

I actually followed the tutorial playlist i have put a link to above to tutorial 12, and that is the point where i have built the program again and started it the first time after the point it all worked properly.

Why is this happening? What could be the problem that lies behind that output?

EDIT: Here is all of my code

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <MainGame.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MainGame mainGame;
    mainGame.Run("Game Engine");
    return 0;
}
```

GLSLProgram.h

```
#ifndef CLASSES_GLSLPROGRAM_H_
#define CLASSES_GLSLPROGRAM_H_

#include <string>
#include <glew.h>

class GLSLProgram
{
public:
    GLSLProgram();
    virtual ~GLSLProgram();

    void CompileShaders(const std::string& filePath);
    void AddAttribute(const std::string& attributeName);
    void LinkShaders();
    void UseProgram();
    void UnUseProgram();
    GLint GetUniformLocation(const std::string& uniformName);

private:
    GLuint m_programID;
    GLuint m_vertexShaderID;
    GLuint m_fragmentShaderID;
    int m_numAttributes;

    void GetShader(const std::string& filePath, const std::string& shaderType, GLuint& shaderID);
};

#endif /* CLASSES_GLSLPROGRAM_H_ */
```

GLSLProgram.cpp

```
#include <GLSLProgram.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "..\Headers\JPKErrors.hpp"

GLSLProgram::GLSLProgram() :
m_programID(0),
m_vertexShaderID(0),
m_fragmentShaderID(0),
m_numAttributes(0)
{
}

GLSLProgram::~GLSLProgram()
{
    if(m_vertexShaderID != 0)
        glDeleteShader(m_vertexShaderID);
    if(m_fragmentShaderID != 0)
        glDeleteShader(m_fragmentShaderID);

    if(m_programID != 0)
        glDeleteProgram(m_programID);
}

void GLSLProgram::CompileShaders(const std::string& filePath)
{
    m_programID = glCreateProgram();

    m_vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    if(m_vertexShaderID == 0)
        jpk::FatalError("Vertex shader could not be created!");

    m_fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    if(m_fragmentShaderID == 0)
        jpk::FatalError("Fragment Shader could not be created!");

    GetShader(filePath + ".vsh", "Vertex", m_vertexShaderID);
    GetShader(filePath + ".fsh", "Fragment", m_fragmentShaderID);
}

void GLSLProgram::AddAttribute(const std::string& attributeName)
{
    glBindAttribLocation(m_programID, m_numAttributes++, attributeName.c_str());
}

void GLSLProgram::LinkShaders()
{
    glAttachShader(m_programID, m_vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(m_programID, m_fragmentShaderID);

    glLinkProgram(m_programID);

    GLint isLinked = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(m_programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int*)&isLinked);
    glDetachShader(m_programID, m_vertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(m_programID, m_fragmentShaderID);

    if(isLinked == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(m_programID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(m_programID, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);

        printf("%s\n", &errorLog[0]);

        jpk::FatalError("Shader program failed to link!\nDetails:");
    }
}

void GLSLProgram::GetShader(const std::string& filePath, const std::string& shaderType, GLuint& shaderID)
{
    std::ifstream shaderFile(filePath);
    if(shaderFile.fail())
        jpk::FatalError(shaderType + " shader file " + filePath + " could not be opened!", false, true, filePath);

    std::string fileContents("");
    std::string line;

    while(getline(shaderFile, line))
        fileContents += line + "\n";

    shaderFile.close();

    const char* charFileContents = fileContents.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &charFileContents, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shaderID);
    GLint success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(success == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &errorLog[0]);
        jpk::FatalError(shaderType + " shader file " + filePath + " failed to compile!\nDetails:");
    }

}

void GLSLProgram::UseProgram()
{
    glUseProgram(m_programID);
    for(int i=0; i < m_numAttributes ;i++)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
}

void GLSLProgram::UnUseProgram()
{
    glUseProgram(0);
    for(int i=0; i < m_numAttributes ;i++)
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(i);
}

GLint GLSLProgram::GetUniformLocation(const std::string& uniformName)
{
    GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(m_programID, uniformName.c_str());
    if(location == (GLint)GL_INVALID_INDEX)
        jpk::FatalError("Uniform \"" + uniformName + "\" was not found in shaders!");
    return location;
}
```

ImageLoader.h

```
#ifndef IMAGELOADER_H
#define IMAGELOADER_H
#include "..\Headers\GLTexture.hpp"
#include <string>

class ImageLoader {
public:
    static GLTexture LoadPNG(const std::string& filePath);
};

#endif /* IMAGELOADER_H */
```

ImageLoader.cpp

```
#include <ImageLoader.h>
#include "..\Headers\picoPNG.hpp"
#include "..\Headers\JPKErrors.hpp"
#include "IOManager.h"
#include <iostream>

GLTexture ImageLoader::LoadPNG(const std::string& filePath)
{
    GLTexture texture = {};

    std::vector<unsigned char> out, in;
    unsigned long width, height;

    if(!IOManager::ReadFileToBuffer(filePath, in))
    {
        jpk::FatalError("Failed to load .png file \"" + filePath + "\" to buffer!");
    }

    int errorCode = decodePNG(out, width, height, &in[0], in.size());
    if(errorCode != 0)
    {
        jpk::FatalError("Could not decode the .png file \"" + filePath + "\" with error code: " + std::to_string(errorCode));
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &texture.ID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.ID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture.width, texture.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &out[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    texture.width = width;
    texture.height = height;

    return texture;
}
```

IOManager.h

```
#ifndef IOMANAGER_H
#define IOMANAGER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class IOManager
{
public:
    static bool ReadFileToBuffer(const std::string& filePath, std::vector<unsigned char>& buffer);
};

#endif /* IOMANAGER_H */
```

IOManager.cpp

```
#include <IOManager.h>
#include <fstream>

bool IOManager::ReadFileToBuffer(const std::string& filePath, std::vector<unsigned char>& buffer)
{
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if(file.fail())
    {
        perror(filePath.c_str());
        return false;
    }

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    buffer.resize(fileSize);
    file.read((char*)&buffer[0], fileSize);

    file.close();
    return true;
}
```

MainGame.h

```
#ifndef MAINGAME_H
#define MAINGAME_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "GLSLProgram.h"
#include "..\Headers\GLTexture.hpp"

class MainGame
{
public:
    MainGame();
    MainGame(int width, int height);
    virtual ~MainGame();

    void Run(const char* windowTitle);

private:
    enum class GameState {PLAY, EXIT};
    SDL_Window* m_window;
    int m_windowWidth;
    int m_windowHeight;
    float m_time;

    Sprite m_sprite;
    GLSLProgram m_colorProgram;
    GLTexture m_playerTexture;

    void InitSystems(const char* windowTitle);
    void GameLoop();
    void ProcessInput();
    void DrawGame();
    void InitShaders();

    GameState m_currentGameState;
};

#endif /* MAINGAME_H_ */
```

MainGame.cpp

```
#include "MainGame.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <glew.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "..\Headers\JPKErrors.hpp"
#include <ImageLoader.h>

MainGame::MainGame() :
m_window(nullptr),
m_windowWidth(800),
m_windowHeight(600),
m_time(0),
m_currentGameState(GameState::PLAY)
{
}

MainGame::MainGame(int width, int height) :
m_window(nullptr),
m_windowWidth(width),
m_windowHeight(height),
m_time(0),
m_currentGameState(GameState::PLAY)
{
}

MainGame::~MainGame()
{
    m_window = nullptr;
    SDL_Quit();
}

void MainGame::Run(const char* windowTitle)
{
    InitSystems(windowTitle);
    GameLoop();
}

void MainGame::InitSystems(const char* windowTitle)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(windowTitle, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, m_windowWidth, m_windowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if(m_window == nullptr)
        jpk::FatalError("SDL Window could not be created!", true);

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);
    if(glContext == nullptr)
        jpk::FatalError("SDL GL Context could not be created out of m_window!", true);

    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if(error != GLEW_OK)
        jpk::FatalError("CLEW could not be initialized!");

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    m_sprite.Init(-0.75, -0.75, 1.5, 1.5);

    m_playerTexture = ImageLoader::LoadPNG("./Files/Images/JimmyJumpPack/PNG/CharacterRight_Standing.png");

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    InitShaders();
}

void MainGame::ProcessInput()
{
    SDL_Event sdlEvent;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent))
    {
        switch(sdlEvent.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT: m_currentGameState = GameState::EXIT; break;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                std::cout << sdlEvent.motion.x << " " << sdlEvent.motion.y << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void MainGame::GameLoop()
{
    while(m_currentGameState != GameState::EXIT)
    {
        try
        {
        ProcessInput();
        m_time += 0.01;
        DrawGame();
        }
        catch(jpk::FatalErrorException& e)
        {
            m_currentGameState = GameState::EXIT;
        }
    }
}

void MainGame::DrawGame()
{
    glClearDepth(1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    m_colorProgram.UseProgram();

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_playerTexture.ID);
    GLint textureLocation = m_colorProgram.GetUniformLocation("textureSampler");
    glUniform1i(textureLocation, 0);

    m_sprite.Draw();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    m_colorProgram.UnUseProgram();

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);
}

void MainGame::InitShaders()
{
    m_colorProgram.CompileShaders("./Files/Shaders/textureShader"); 
    m_colorProgram.AddAttribute("vertexPosition");
    m_colorProgram.AddAttribute("vertexColor");
    m_colorProgram.AddAttribute("vertexUV");
    m_colorProgram.LinkShaders();
}
```

Sprite.h

```
#ifndef SPRITE_H_
#define SPRITE_H_

#include <glew.h>

class Sprite
{
public:
    Sprite();
    virtual ~Sprite();

    void Init(float x, float y, float width, float height);
    void Draw();

private:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
    float m_width;
    float m_height;
    GLuint m_vertexBufferObjectID;
};

#endif /* SPRITE_H_ */
```

Sprite.cpp

```
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "../Headers/JPKVertex.hpp"
#include <cstddef>

Sprite::Sprite() :
m_x(0),
m_y(0),
m_width(0),
m_height(0)
{
    m_vertexBufferObjectID = 0;
}

Sprite::~Sprite()
{
    if(m_vertexBufferObjectID != 0)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_vertexBufferObjectID);
}

void Sprite::Init(float x, float y, float width, float height)
{
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;

    if(m_vertexBufferObjectID == 0)
    {
        glGenBuffers(1, &m_vertexBufferObjectID);
    }

    jpk::Vertex vertexData[6];

    vertexData[0].SetPosition(x+width, y+height);
    vertexData[0].SetUV(1.0f, 1.0f);

    vertexData[1].SetPosition(x, y+height);
    vertexData[1].SetUV(0.0f, 1.0f);

    vertexData[2].SetPosition(x, y);
    vertexData[2].SetUV(0.0f, 0.0f);

    vertexData[3].SetPosition(x, y);
    vertexData[3].SetUV(0.0f, 0.0f);

    vertexData[4].SetPosition(x+width, y);
    vertexData[4].SetUV(1.0f, 0.0f);

    vertexData[5].SetPosition(x+width, y+height);
    vertexData[5].SetUV(1.0f, 1.0f);

    for(int i=0; i < 6 ;i++)
    {
        vertexData[i].SetColor(255, 0, 255, 255);
    }

    vertexData[1].SetColor(0, 0, 255, 255);
    vertexData[4].SetColor(0, 255, 0, 255);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBufferObjectID);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void Sprite::Draw()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBufferObjectID);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(jpk::Vertex), (void*)offsetof(jpk::Vertex, position));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(jpk::Vertex), (void*)offsetof(jpk::Vertex, color));
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(jpk::Vertex), (void*)offsetof(jpk::Vertex, uv));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

GLTexture.hpp

```
#ifndef GLTEXTURE_HPP
#define GLTEXTURE_HPP

#include <glew.h>

struct GLTexture
{
    GLuint ID;
    int width;
    int height;
};

#endif /* GLTEXTURE_HPP */
```

JPKErrors.hpp

```
#ifndef JPKERRORS_HPP
#define JPKERRORS_HPP

#include <string>
#include "JPKExceptions.hpp"

namespace jpk
{
    void FatalError(const std::string& errorString, bool isSDLRelated = false, bool usePError = false, const std::string& file = "   ");
}
#endif  //JPKERRORS_HPP
```

JPKErrors.cpp

```
#include "JPKErrors.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <missingmingw\mingw.thread.h>

namespace jpk
{
    extern void FatalError(const std::string& errorString, bool isSDLRelated, bool usePError, const std::string& file)
    {
        std::cerr << "Fatal Error: " << errorString << std::endl;
        if(isSDLRelated)
            std::cerr << "SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
        if(usePError && file != "   ")
        {
            std::cout << "Error Details: ";
            perror(file.c_str());
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        std::cout << "This application will now close..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        throw FatalErrorException();
    }
}
```

JPKExceptions.hpp

```
namespace jpk
{
    class FatalErrorException{};
}
```

JPKVertex.hpp

```
#ifndef JPKVERTEX_H
#define JPKVERTEX_H

#include <glew.h>

namespace jpk
{
    struct VertexPosition
    {
        float x;
        float y;
    };

    struct VertexColor
    {
        GLubyte r;
        GLubyte g;
        GLubyte b;
        GLubyte a;
    };

    struct VertexUV
    {
        float u;
        float v;
    };

    struct Vertex
    {
        VertexPosition position;
        VertexColor color;
        VertexUV uv;

        void SetColor(GLubyte r, GLubyte g, GLubyte b, GLubyte a)
        {
            color.r = r;
            color.g = g;
            color.b = b;
            color.a = a;
        }

        void SetPosition(float x, float y)
        {
            position.x = x;
            position.y = y;
        }

        void SetUV(float u, float v)
        {
            uv.u = u;
            uv.v = v;
        }
    };
}

#endif /* JPKVERTEX_H */
```

picoPNG.hpp

```
#ifndef PICOPNG_HPP
#define PICOPNG_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <stddef.h>

extern int decodePNG(std::vector<unsigned char>& out_image, unsigned long& image_width, unsigned long& image_height, const unsigned char* in_png, size_t in_size, bool convert_to_rgba32 = true);

#endif /* PICOPNG_HPP */
```

And picoPNG.cpp is too big to fit in here, so instead, here is a link to where i have downlaoded picoPNG:

http://lodev.org/lodepng/

I also did some debugging myself by adding the line

```
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
```

At the top of int main() before all the other code. Even that did not get put out into the console, just the error message i described above.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add some code *directly within your question* to facilitate the problem resolution. Otherwise you will get down-voted.

Comment: Have you tried running it in debugger?

Comment: @Mr_Pouet Yes, of course, but it is quite a lot of code

Comment: @AdrianKrupa For some odd reason the inbuilt Debugger in Eclipse CDT does not work, so i have to do the debugging myself. But i did that, as i have described in the question now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you used `ImageLoader::LoadPNG("./Files/Images/JimmyJumpPack/PNG/CharacterRight_Standing.png");`

Try using the full filepath, that worked for me.
(`loadPNG("C:\\Users\\...\\filename.png");`)

If you look in [picopng.cpp](http://lodev.org/lodepng/picopng.cpp) you'll find why you're getting error: 48 on line 259:
`if(size == 0 || in == 0) { error = 48; return; } //the given data is empty`

So it must have not found the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `picoPNG.cpp` has a `main` function in it! This will conflict with your own `main` function. So open up `picoPNG.cpp` and comment out its `main` function.